# Set LAN / WLAN Auto Switching on newer HP laptops

Tags: vbscript, bios, wmic

I have been trying to write a vbs script that I can use as a deployment in SCCM 2012, that will turn the bios feature "LAN / WLAN Auto Switching" on for laptops.
I found this article http://www.kozeniauskas.com/itblog/2008/01/18/remotely-change-bios-settings/. But The line **objItem.SetBiosSetting oReturn, "LAN/WLAN Switching", "Enable", "<kbd/>"** does not seem to work correctly for newer laptops. It does work for older laptops.

That same article had a script for dumping all the names of properties. It seems that on the 9480 laptops it is called "LAN/WLAN Switching", but on the 1040 laptops the feature is called "LAN / WLAN Auto Switching". I have tried plugging that name into the same line, but it will not enable LAN/WLAN Switching.

The white paper, that HP has published, does not have the specific properties that can be used with SetBiosSetting. http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/cmi_whitepaper.pdf It did tell me that the oReturn value of 4 just means failure.

Currently my code looks like...

Detecting the bios setting (Working for both models):

```
Dim objFileSystem, strReturn

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 16
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = 32

lFlags = wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly
strService = "winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}//"
strComputer = "."
strNamespace = "/root/HP/InstrumentedBIOS"
strQuery = "select * from HP_BIOSSetting where name like '%Switching%' AND name like '%LAN%'"
strReturn = "Fail"

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objWMIService = GetObject(strService & strComputer & strNamespace)
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery,,lFlags)

For Each objItem In colItems
If objItem.Value = " Disable, *Enable" then strReturn = "Success"
Next

Set objFileSystem = Nothing

wscript.echo strReturn
```

Set bios setting script (Works only on 9480):

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 16
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = 32
lFlags = wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly
strService = "winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}//"
strComputer = "."
strNamespace = "/root/HP/InstrumentedBIOS"
strQuery = "select * from HP_BIOSSettingInterface"
Set objWMIService = GetObject(strService & strComputer & strNamespace)
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery,,lFlags)
For each objItem in colItems
objItem.SetBiosSetting oReturn, "LAN/WLAN Switching", "Enable", "<kbd/>"
Next
```

I would like to avoid using the HP Bios Configuration Utility.

Comment: In addition to updating the name, they updated the possible states. It is no longer "Enable" but should be "Enabled".
For the 1040s the line should be...
**objItem.SetBiosSetting oReturn, "LAN/WLAN Switching", "Enabled", "<kbd/>"**

Answer (score 0):

Turns out they updated the property from "Enable" to "Enabled".
My code now looks like...

Get WLAN_LAN:

```
Dim objFileSystem, strReturn

Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 16
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = 32

lFlags = wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly
strService = "winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}//"
strComputer = "."
strNamespace = "/root/HP/InstrumentedBIOS"
strQuery = "select * from HP_BIOSSetting where name like '%Switching%' AND name like '%LAN%'"
strReturn = "Fail"

Set objFileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.fileSystemObject")
Set objWMIService = GetObject(strService & strComputer & strNamespace)
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery,,lFlags)

For Each objItem In colItems
If objItem.Value = " Disable, *Enable" OR objItem.Value = "Disabled,*Enabled" then strReturn = "Success"
Next

Set objFileSystem = Nothing


wscript.echo strReturn
```

Set WLAN_LAN:

```
Const wbemFlagReturnImmediately = 16
Const wbemFlagForwardOnly = 32
lFlags = wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly
strService = "winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}//"
strComputer = "."
strNamespace = "/root/HP/InstrumentedBIOS"
strQuery = "select * from HP_BIOSSettingInterface"
Set objWMIService = GetObject(strService & strComputer & strNamespace)
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(strQuery,,lFlags)
For each objItem in colItems
objItem.SetBiosSetting oReturn, "LAN/WLAN Switching", "Enable", "<kbd/>"
if oReturn <> 0 then objItem.SetBiosSetting oReturn, "LAN / WLAN Auto Switching", "Enabled", "<kbd/>"
Next
```

I'll probably clean these up and make them uniform, but thee should work in both cases. I'll probably also use inStr to detect if its enabled.